# Error with import android.support.annotation.NonNull

Tags: android

[NonNull class Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UyeTT.png)

I did not find this .class or jar to correct this error.
Can you help?

Comment: Try just deleting import line. If it doesn't help try to find the code instruction referring to this import.

Answer (score 4):

Add the appropriate dependency in your gradle file as specified in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/annotations.html).

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:24.2.0'
```

Answer (score 2):

replace with import androidx.annotation.NonNull;